# Генератор звуковой частоты

Tags: php, аудио, javascript

Мне нужен скрипт генератора звуковой частоты желательно на php или javascript. Или подскажите какой нибуть сайт с онлайн генератором звуковой частоты ( только не gorchilin.com). Заранее благодарвствую.

Comment: http://www.htmlfivewow.com/demos/waveform-generator/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать линуховые проги для этих целей? Например, `beep` или `sox`.

Запустите программу с нужными параметрами из скрипта PHP через `exec()` - и будет вам счастье! :)

Comment: А можно по подробнее п то я не оч понял

Comment: Устанавливаете `sox` на сервер

В коде PHP пишете что-то на подобии этого

    <?php
        exec('sox −n output.wav synth 3 sine 300−3300');

В результате получаете файл output.wav с нужным звуком

Comment: Спасибо это тоже понадобится но в данный момент мне нужно что бы люди сами регулировали параметры и могли сразу же прослушать

Comment: В чем сложность подставить в эту строку параметры, заданные пользователем? )